# Update XML file with python - add new UserName and FeatureIds

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am new to python and XML. I need to add UserName and all his corresponding FeatureIds into the XML file. Any help will be greatly appreciated. For example I want to add UserName john@abc.com and his FeatureIds 3,5,6.  It can be any where in users list i.e at the beginning or middle or at the end but same structure like other user Names. Thanks in advance.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BusinessRule>
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CovRDMMetaData>
        <Config>
            <Type>Business Rule</Type>
            <Category>Device</Category>
        </Config>
        <Properties>
            <PropertyInfo>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>FeatureEntitlementDetails</Name>
                    <Path>Rules\FeatureEntitlementDetails.xml</Path>
                    <Version>4.0.12</Version>
                </Rule>
                <Target>
                    <ClientName>Money Exchange Client</ClientName>
                    <ClientVersion>7.8.7</ClientVersion>
                    <DeviceType>Money AP15</DeviceType>
                </Target>
            </PropertyInfo>
        </Properties>
    </CovRDMMetaData>
    <CovRDMData>
        <SetFeatureRetirement>
             <IsRetired>No</IsRetired>
             <MessageIfRetired>Please upgrade ROLEX client to use Set Feature option</MessageIfRetired>
       </SetFeatureRetirement>
       <EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
           <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>raj@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>mana@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>thomas@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
                          <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>anyka@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
       </EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
    </CovRDMData>
</BusinessRule>
```

Expected ouput:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BusinessRule>
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CovRDMMetaData>
        <Config>
            <Type>Business Rule</Type>
            <Category>Device</Category>
        </Config>
        <Properties>
            <PropertyInfo>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>FeatureEntitlementDetails</Name>
                    <Path>Rules\FeatureEntitlementDetails.xml</Path>
                    <Version>4.0.12</Version>
                </Rule>
                <Target>
                    <ClientName>Money Exchange Client</ClientName>
                    <ClientVersion>7.8.7</ClientVersion>
                    <DeviceType>Money AP15</DeviceType>
                </Target>
            </PropertyInfo>
        </Properties>
    </CovRDMMetaData>
    <CovRDMData>
        <SetFeatureRetirement>
             <IsRetired>No</IsRetired>
             <MessageIfRetired>Please upgrade ROLEX client to use Set Feature option</MessageIfRetired>
       </SetFeatureRetirement>
       <EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
       
       ***
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>john@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>                 
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>  
       ***
       
           <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>raj@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>mana@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>thomas@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
                          <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>anyka@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
       </EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
    </CovRDMData>
</BusinessRule>
```

I added *** at beginning and ending where I need to add new UserName and his FeatureIds
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Ram Can you pls look into this?

Comment: Share the expected output. Assuming what you have shares already is the input. Explain **exactly** how the xml document is changed.

Comment: @balderman I have edited the question. Added expected output

Comment: So you want to add a new `FeatureEntitlementDetail` - right?

Comment: Yes. I want to add new `FeatureEntitlementDetail` with his username and featureIds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below. (The idea is to create a new `FeatureEntitlementDetail`, populate it and append it to the doc in the right place.)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BusinessRule>
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CovRDMMetaData>
        <Config>
            <Type>Business Rule</Type>
            <Category>Device</Category>
        </Config>
        <Properties>
            <PropertyInfo>
                <Rule>
                    <Name>FeatureEntitlementDetails</Name>
                    <Path>Rules\FeatureEntitlementDetails.xml</Path>
                    <Version>4.0.12</Version>
                </Rule>
                <Target>
                    <ClientName>Money Exchange Client</ClientName>
                    <ClientVersion>7.8.7</ClientVersion>
                    <DeviceType>Money AP15</DeviceType>
                </Target>
            </PropertyInfo>
        </Properties>
    </CovRDMMetaData>
    <CovRDMData>
        <SetFeatureRetirement>
             <IsRetired>No</IsRetired>
             <MessageIfRetired>Please upgrade ROLEX client to use Set Feature option</MessageIfRetired>
       </SetFeatureRetirement>
       <EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
           <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>raj@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>mana@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
            <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>thomas@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>0</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>1</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>2</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>3</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>                    
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>4</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>5</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>6</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>8</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>9</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>10</FeatureId>           
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
                          <FeatureEntitlementDetail>
              <UserName>anyka@abc.com</UserName>
              <FeatureList>
                    <FeatureDetail>
                        <FeatureId>7</FeatureId>            
                    </FeatureDetail>
                </FeatureList>
            </FeatureEntitlementDetail>
       </EnabledFeatureListForUsers>
    </CovRDMData>
</BusinessRule>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

data = {'UserName':'john@abc.com','Features':[3,5,6]}

details = ET.Element("FeatureEntitlementDetail")
user_name = ET.SubElement(details,'UserName')
user_name.text = data['UserName']
feature_list = ET.SubElement(details,'FeatureList')

for f in data['Features']:
  ele = ET.SubElement(feature_list,'FeatureDetail')
  sub_ele = ET.SubElement(ele,'FeatureId')
  sub_ele.text = str(f)
root.find('.//EnabledFeatureListForUsers').append(details)
ET.dump(root)
```

Comment: we need to add `<FeatureList>` tag also after `UserName` tag, Could you pls modify the code?

Comment: OK. Code was updated. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: It is very important that you will spend time to understand the code so you will learn from it.

Comment: Why not find `<EnabledFeatureListForUsers>` node and create `SubElement` on this node instead of appending it after?